# Describe SOAP Call gives 404 message

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to do a describe call for ImportDefinition object and I get the 404 error message. I do not understand why.

I have attached the Headers I am passing and the SOAP envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-31606811" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>XXXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>ImportDefinition</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response I get is:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Server Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
                <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
                    unavailable.</h3>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

I tried changing the soap action in the header from "create" to "describe" but that didn't make any difference.

I have also tried to change the SOAP endpoint with the tenant:
[image]

Comment: why does your end point have http/1.1 in it?

Comment: I was getting this error message so I added this in the header: 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24767/exacttarget-soap-request-returns-fault-in-response

Comment: I would recommend you review this doc for your TSE endpoint for SOAP https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm should be something like mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.soap.marketingcloudapis.com

Comment: Thanks, yes i did that and I have updated the post, I get the error message that I cannot connect

Answer (score 0):

To Assist here is a working configuration for postman:

[image]

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Describe</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>ImportDefinition</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can also download an API collection from salesforce from their [GIT hub](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-postman)